# jQuery slider - unexpected behaviour

Tags: jquery

I wrote small 'News Ticker'. I should make a loop through the `spans`, making fadeIn/fadeOut every 5s.

**While untouched it is working fine, but when you try do play with the arrows(play forward arrow 5 times for example), script goes mad making fadeIn/fadeOut constatly.**

**[Live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/t4NXD/40/)**

Script:

```
        (function($) {

        $.fn.NoticeBoard = function() {


            // Set a timeout
            var timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);

            // pause on hover
            $('.noticeboard').hover(

            function() {
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
            }, function() {
                timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);
            });

            // Next notice function called on timeout or click

            function nextNotice(event) {
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
                timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);

                if ($('.noticeboard span:visible').is('.noticeboard span:last-child')) {
                    $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300);
                    $('.noticeboard span:first-child').fadeIn();
                }
                else {
                    $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300).next().fadeIn();
                }
                return false;
            }

            $('#notice-next').click(nextNotice);
            $('#notice-prev').click(function(event) {


                if ($('.noticeboard span:visible').is('.noticeboard span:first-child')) {
                    $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300);
                    $('.noticeboard span:last-child').fadeIn();
                }
                else {
                    $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300).prev().fadeIn();
                }
                return false;

            });

        };

    /*!  
    ---------------------------------------------*/

    })(jQuery);

    /*!  OnLoad
    ---------------------------------------------*/
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.noticeboard span').hide();
        $('.noticeboard span:first').show();
        $('.noticeboard').NoticeBoard();

    });
```

Any help with fixing the issue much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I tried it here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4NXD/60/)
I declare a flag to carry the fadeIn is already done or not,so that we can never fire the event too much times...

Comment: How to implement same principle for prev click?

Comment: u can also use that flag, and edit ur prev click code like next code~~~

Comment: Got that working with prev event as well. Very clever solutions. Thanks!

Comment: lol,I'm very happy that my mind is helpful for u~PS:can u teach me english?I always think I can't explain my mind clear.That's so bad

Comment: @NewUser let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2844/discussion-between-zhzhzhh-and-newuser)

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code. You can see it live [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9dDxL/13/). It is all about blocking flag which doesn't let you run the same code too many times. And I wrapped management of setTimeout and clearTimeout for better control I think.